# how use import a scala project created with sbt in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I have created a scala project using sbt as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585211/how-can-i-use-apache-math-with-scala/25585390#25585390)
Now I want to import this project into eclipse.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a plugin such as [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) to genereate the sbt project

**For sbt 0.13 and up** (from the above link)

Add sbteclipse to your plugin definition file. You can use either:
the global file (for version 0.13 and up) at `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt`
the project-specific file at `PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt`

> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" %
>   "2.5.0")

In sbt use the command `eclipse` to create Eclipse project files
eclipse

In Eclipse use the Import Wizard to import Existing Projects into Workspace